# How to explain the following C code snippet?

Tags: c, gcc

Gcc version:

**gcc 4.4.3**

The code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct str {
    int len;
    char s[0];
};

struct test {
    struct str *p_str;
};

int main()
{
    struct test t = { 0 };
    if (t.p_str->s)     // FLAG_0
        printf("here!");
    printf(t.p_str->s); // FLAG_1
    return 0;
}
```

I got a error when I run the code:**Segmentation fault**

I use the gdb to debug. I found it crashed at the **FLAG_1**

I am confused about it.

**It ran OK at FLAG_0, but crashed at FLAG_1. Why ?**

Meanwhile, I found **the value of t.p_str is 0x00**. I don't understand the if case is OK.

Note: The code is just for the study!

Comment: `t.p_str->s` is undefined behavior. The code running okay at `FLAG_0` and crashing at `FLAG_1` should not be relied upon. That could change depending on the platform your code runs on, or even between different runs on the same platform.

Comment: Your are trying to access NULL pointer.

Comment: I doubt s[0] is valid! Coz char s[1] is "char s"

Comment: This isn't C++, please retag

Comment: Also take a look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: I think OP wanted to know howcome he's not getting SEGFAULT in the if condition, but he encounters it in the print statement. Even I would be stumped by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `s` is an array, not a pointer, it will never be null. So the compiler is free to omit the check, and assume it isn't null. If it does that, then `FLAG_0` will not attempt to dereference the null pointer, so you won't get a segmentation fault at that point.

Of course, it's free to do anything else it feels like, since the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. But I get the value of **f.p_str** by **Gdb:(gdb)p f.p_str** , and the result is :**(gdb) $2 = (struct str*) 0x0**. Thus, I think the value of **p_str** variable is NULL. I can't understand the **t.p_str->s** statement is OK, since I think **NULL->s** is invalid. You said **FLAG_0** will not attempt to dereference the null pointer, the output of the code snippet is **here**. So the value of **if** case should be non-zero. How to get it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about C++ it's illegal to declare an array of length 0. C++11 *§8.3.4 Arrays*:

> If the constant-expression is present, it shall be an integral
>   constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

The *constant-expression* here is the array length. However, the standard allows creating zero length arrays dynamically using `new`.

If you're talking about C, then it's already entered undefined behaviour territory at *FLAG_0* and thus nothing that happens afterwards is warranted by the language.

Comment: This explains why it shouldn't compile under a strict C++ compiler; but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You declared an Array with 0 elements. `char s[0];`.
An empty string has at least one element, a binary zero.

This `struct test t = { 0 };` does not initialise your structure to 0. It initialises your first element to 0. In this special case you just create a null pointer.

You can initialise using memset.

```
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int len;
    char s[10];
}MyStr;

int main()
{
    MyStr str;
    memset(&str, 0, sizeof(MyStr));
}
```

One statement dereferences a nullpointer: `printf(t.p_str->s);` tries to resolve `t.p_str->s` with `t.p_str` beeing `0`.

Answer (score -1):

So first of all, the code is total rubbish and invokes undefined behaviour in multiple places, so anything can happen, including crashes or non crashes, unexpected or not.

What is t.p_str->s ?

s is an array. If t.p_str were a valid pointer, then t.p_str->s would be the address of the first character in the s array. That's a pointer, it's not a null pointer, so for the "if" statement that counts as a true result. The compiler doesn't actually need to evaluate the whole expression, because it doesn't care *what* pointer it is, only that it isn't a null pointer. That's why t.p_str->s doesn't crash here, because the program never evaluates it.

In the printf statement, the actual value of t.p_str->s is needed, so that one crashes.